# KDB how to join a list of tables to another table

Tags: kdb

Given table a:

```
a:([] sym:`a`b`c; qty: 1 2 3)
```

And list of tables t:

```
t:(([] sym:`a`b`c; qty:1 2 3; price: 1.1 2.2 3.3); ([] sym:`a`b`c; qty:3 4 5; length:100 200 300))
```

Desired Outcome:

| sym | qty | price | length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1.1 | 100 |
| b | 2 | 1.2 | 200 |
| c | 3 | 3.3 | 300 |

How do I join certain elements of t to table a?

Since t is a list of tables, how can we break up / convert this list into a more  "retrieval friendly" table?

Comment: Can you share with us your desired output? Do you want to join one of the tables or all of the tables in `t` to `a`?

Comment: added the desired output, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the easiest way to join the tables in the way you want to is to key each table by `sym` and `lj` them to `a`.

We can key each table by `sym` like so:

```
q)1!'t
(+(,`sym)!,`a`b`c)!+`qty`price!(1 2 3;1.1 2.2 3.3)
(+(,`sym)!,`a`b`c)!+`qty`length!(3 4 5;100 200 300)
```

An `lj` will join the fields & values in the right hand table to the left hand table for keys which match. The use of `/` (over) below ensures the return from the first `lj` is used in the second `lj` (Two left-joins as there are two tables to join).

```
q)lj/[a;reverse 1!'t]
sym qty length price
--------------------
a   1   100    1.1
b   2   200    2.2
c   3   300    3.3
```

I've used `reverse` to ensure the first table is joined last so that `qty` matches your desired output.

If the order of the fields is important you can use `xcols`:

```
q)`sym`qty`price xcols lj/[a;reverse 1!'t]
sym qty price length
--------------------
a   1   1.1   100
b   2   2.2   200
c   3   3.3   300
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help!

when i try to set the first column as keys (1!`t), i get this:

(([] sym)!kx.c$Flip@6ab657fe;([] sym)!kx.c$Flip@746de55a)

do i have a syntax error? it doesnt seem to want to key the sym column

Comment: I think the issue here is that you are using a backtick ` instead of an apostrophe (`'`) for `1!'t`.

Comment: I think you're just seeing it in that form because you're viewing it in qStudio (or some other IDE). That's how qStudio represents a list of keyed tables. Switch to the "console" view for an alternative view. Either way the underlying kdb object is in line with Cathals